# USB camera node not getting created on Android

Tags: android, file, camera, usb, device

How and who(driver or any daemon) creates a node when a device is inserted in the Android tablet?

When I connect USB camera to Acer Iconia tablet, `/dev/video1` is created, but it does not gets created in Samsung Galaxy tab.

My goal is to get the node created on galaxy tab. I have the source code (based on samsung device version(GTP7510) downloaded from [opensource.samsung.com](http://opensource.samsung.com)).

To understand what needs to be done, I need to understand how and who creates the node. Is it driver that creates the node or is it a daemon that creates the node or is it something else? Kindly throw some light on this.

If I am not clear on my requirement please comment, I will reply with more details.

Comment: StackOverflow historically has not been a good resource for Android firmware issues. You may wish to visit http://source.android.com and find a relevant Google Group there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The inbuilt kernel needs to have support for the USB camera stuff. You need to enable UVC and V4l2 modules inside the kernel. Do make menuconfig and then I had to mark UVC and V4L2 support and then compile the code and flash it on the device. Initially iIwas having problem coz i was not able to flash on the Samsung tabs because of proprietary stuff and all. But when I experimented it on Panda board. I was able to get the node created.

Comment: Hey can you pls explain how to configure defconf to enable UVC and V4L2?

Comment: @Anirudh You can run the command "make menuconfig" (I hope you know the location from where you need to run this command). After that you will see a blue window opening up. Once you have a blue window, go inside drivers and inside that search for media and inside it you will have v4l2/UVC (Its been a long time and i dont exactly remember the path. But it is easily findable. I dont have access to a linux repository else i would have done that)

Comment: Ah, Finally,The nodes are getting created. But it shows the file size as `0.00 B`. Is it normal?

Comment: not sure. What is the major and minor number? it should be 81,0 or 81,1

Comment: all the file managers say 0B. Interestingly, my keyboard stop appearing once I plug-in the cam. So cant use the shell also.

Comment: take the IP address of it and login from your desktop machine using rlogin or you can use adb connect - Search in internet for adb connect. It works. Check if the major number is 81 or not. Also, you can connect the camera to linux desktop machine and check in /dev/vid*. You should find a node created with major number 81

Comment: Yes on desktop the cam's major number is 81.  To use adb how do I connect the phone to computer?  I would have connected the cam to the USB port.

Comment: I feel the problem lies in the permission. The logcat shows `/dev/video0 : Permission denied`. The file manager shows its  permission as 600. Modified ueventd.riogrande.rc. Still no luck!

Comment: Definite;y it means you should try as a root

Comment: Before doing logcat, do su and change to root mode. You would get # prompt which means you are in root mode. But for this to work, your devi e needs to be rooted. And the procedure for this differes from device to device. Once you are in # prompt, you can change the permissions by chmod 777 /dev/video0 and then use it from application. At this point in time dont worry abt the final solution but try to seee something from camera.

Comment: But as I told you before my keyboard stops appearing as soon as I plug in the camera. So can't do anything on shell. Before I plug in the camera theres no node to change permission.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14734/discussion-between-anirudh-and-sandy)

Comment: you can do adb connect. I have replied before. You can check how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will resolve your doubts

uvc_scan_device scan the uvc compliant devices and calls a function uvc_register_chains , which internally calls uvc_register_video , which is responsible for creating the node.

is_seclist is a function in whitelist.h , which has been called during usb registration , you should get some logs like Device- **** &&&& is not supported , as usb registration has been not supported for your device , due to some security reasons , for this your may try to disable whilelist feature or add your device in that list , as i have tried but didn't find the way to flash the image in TABLET .